# How to use custom-defined R functions in Script_Real() in Tableau?

Tags: r, tableau-api

I am trying to use custom-defined (user-defined) R functions (which say takes in 2 real vectors as inputs and gives a real vector as output) to create calculated columns in Tableau using Script_Real() function. I have seen library functions being used. But I have not seen any instance of using UDFs nor any instructions for the same. Is it possible to do so without creating a new library for R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by placing your r file with your function somewhere on R machine. Then tableau calculated field can look like this

```
    SCRIPT_REAL('
setwd("/path/to/your/working/dir")
source("your_r_file.r")
your_function(param1 = .arg1, param2 = .arg2,)
', [tableau_param1], [tableau_param2])
```

- **setwd** sets working dir to the location where your script
  resides.
- **source** loads your R script
- **your_function** calls your
  function with arguments from tableau

You can improve performance of your script calls by configuring RServe to load your file at startup.